# Opening /dev/ttyUSB0 returns "Bad file descriptor"

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, usbserial, xbee

I've been working for quite while on little project of mine with some XBee's. Until now all the code has been tested and working on a UBUNTU-SERVER 10.04 LTS, making use of the *libftdi* libraries for serial-usb simulation/conversion.

At the beginning of this week, I've tried to use the exact same code on a laptop with kubuntu 12.04 make using of the same library versions of *libftdi*.

The thing is that, in my Satellite L755 - 18K laptop, every time I now try to open my XBee device at */dev/ttyUSB0*, it gives me "Bad file descriptor". From the log messages from *dmesg*, the device registers quite normally and can't seem to put my finger one it.

Here it is the part of code used to open the device:

```
cfmakeraw(&tio);
cfsetospeed(&tio,B9600);            // 9600 baud
cfsetispeed(&tio,B9600);            // 9600 baud
tio.c_cc[VMIN]=0;
tio.c_cc[VTIME]=10;

serial_fd=open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);

tcsetattr(serial_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);


if (serial_fd < 0){

    cout << "Error while opening device... " << "errno = " << errno << endl;

    printf("Something went wrong with open()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Any thoughts on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Nope! Running it as my normal user.

Comment: Well try running it as root since you request RDWR on /dev/* :) I need to run sermon as root on my system when I want to get RDRW access to /dev/ttyUSBx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `Frédéric's` answer and then make sure you have permission to open the device.
I need to be root to access (perhaps only to get write permission to) `/dev/ttyUSB0` on my system. I think it's distro-dependent because on Debian I was able to open it as a regular user but I need to be root on my Arch distro. Might be possible to fix by looking at groups and permissions for /dev/ttyUSBx.

EDIT: Actually I'm able to get a file descriptor with a simple test program, so it might be a sermon-specific problem in my case.

Simple solution might be to run the program as root.

Comment: Check your hotplug scripts, they will control the access mode (permission, basically) given to the device node.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're calling `open()` and `tcsetattr()` in sequence, then only check afterwards for an error condition with the file.

Consider `open()` fails for some reason. It will return `-1` and set `errno` to that reason. However, the code in your question proceeds into calling `tcsetattr()` nonetheless, which *will* fail since `serial_fd` will be `-1` in our case, and will overwrite `errno` with the reason why (`EBADF`, `-1` is not a valid file descriptor).

You should instead check for an error condition immediately after opening the file:

```
serial_fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);
if (serial_fd < 0) {
    cout << "Error while opening device... " << "errno = " << errno << endl;
    perror("Something went wrong with open()");
    exit(1);
}
```

And only then, issue:

```
tcsetattr(serial_fd, TCSANOW, &tio);
```

Comment: That is an issue, but not "the" issue if I understood the author correctly. I understood the question as "why do I get Bad filedescriptor when trying to open /dev/ttyUSB0", or did I misinterpret something? :)

Comment: @Jite, you understood correctly indeed, and the answer is *questioner is getting `EBADF` because he's calling `tcsetattr()` before checking that `serial_fd` is valid.* Accessing `errno` immediately after the call to `open()` will allow him to see the actual reason why it fails.

Comment: You are right of course. (My guess is that it will give something like: Permission denied)

Comment: @Jite, yup. Or, worse, `No such device`.

Comment: @Jite Yes! that's right, in fact I was wondering why the "Bad file descriptor error". Nevertheless, I think Frédéric presented a good point. I've changed the code as suggested, and the errno was actually overwritten. What is actually happening, is that, after all, I don't have permission to open the device! :-\

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Touché Frédéric! Exactly that!... looking at the device access permissions, it makes perfect sense that I don't have access to it, but on the other hand it worked perfectly well on my ubuntu-server.

Comment: I'll add what I've written in comments as an answer so that others might see it more likely if they get the same problem. +1 to Frédéric for noting the common mistake often causing confusion :).